# Explicit integration of Kahler form to get volume

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Consider a compact Kaehler manifold $X$ of dimension $d=3$. The K"ahler form in local coordinates $z^i,\bar{z}^i$ is
$$ 
\omega = \omega_{i \bar{j}}dz^i \wedge d\bar{z}^j,
$$
with $\omega_{i \bar{j}} = \frac{i}{2} g_{i \bar{j}}$, where $g_{i \bar{j}}$ is Hermitian.

I want to explicitly show that the volume given by $\int_X \omega^n $ yields
$$
A \int_X \sqrt{\mathrm{det}(g_{i\bar{j}}) } dz^1\wedge dz^2 \wedge dz^3 \wedge d\bar{z}^1 \wedge d\bar{z}^2 \wedge d\bar{z}^3,
$$
where $A$ is some overall constant.

The closest I arrive at my intended result is:
$$
\int_X \epsilon^{i k m} \epsilon^{\bar{j} \bar{l} \bar{n} } 
~ \omega_{i \bar{j}} \omega_{k \bar{l}} \omega_{m \bar{n} } 
~ dz^1\wedge dz^2 \wedge dz^3 \wedge d\bar{z}^1 \wedge d\bar{z}^2 \wedge d\bar{z}^3,
$$
using the antisymmetry of the wedge product and the identity
$$
dz^i \wedge dz^k \wedge dz^m  = \epsilon^{i k m} dz^1\wedge dz^2 \wedge dz^3
$$

and its complex conjugate.

I'm almost convinced that I can identify
$ \epsilon^{i k m} \epsilon^{\bar{j} \bar{l} \bar{n} } 
~ \omega_{i \bar{j}}\omega_{k \bar{l}} \omega_{m \bar{n} }  = \mathrm{det} (\omega_{i \bar{j}})$,
but not 100% sure.

(FWIW, I have seen a version of this where the $dz^i , d\bar{z}^j$'s are turned into real forms $dx^i, dy^j$, but I want to avoid going down that route for the moment and express the result in complex coordinates.)

EDIT: The factor $\sqrt{\mathrm{det}(g_{i\bar{j}}) }$ should not have a square root if it is the hermitian metric, however the real Riemannian metric it is associated to will be square rooted, i.e.
$$
\sqrt{\mathrm{det}(g_{\mu \nu}(x,y) )} = \mathrm{det}(g_{i\bar{j}}(z, 
\bar{z}) )
$$

Comment: You will get an additional factor of $3!=6$ (which of course you can absorb into $A$) because you allow $i,k,m$ to also vary instead of the usual fixed $(i,k,m)=(1,2,3)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, that sounds sensible - thanks

Comment: @nonreligious Choose normal coordinates?